# Can't get Auth0 JWT authentication in Rails 4 working with Knock

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, auth0

I've followed the quick start guide in Auth0 for Rails API [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/rails) but sending authenticable requests to my Rails API always returns 500. There is a JWT in the header and I believe it is valid because copying it to [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/), pasting my private key into the "secret" input, and clicking "secret base64 encoded" shows "verified".

Relevant code below:

Request info:

```
Request URL:https://railie-p0lska1.c9users.io/api/feedbacks.json
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:104.155.203.100:443
```

Request headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3JhaWxpZS5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiZmFjZWJvb2t8NTA0MjI0NjEzIiwiYXVkIjoidHhKQXJNODhsTnNtcGpSRjBlZGZXZHlnY2gyMGJFb0QiLCJleHAiOjE0ODM2MjAyNzcsImlhdCI6MTQ4MzU4NDI3N30.KePQsrTFjQjIzB6YmxzJcbhMW6by7WIBOpm51viaDZE
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:10
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:c9.live.user.jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjcxNjI5OSIsIm5hbWUiOiJwMGxza2ExIiwiY29kZSI6IjljWWhzZXc2TXhtZkN2WFNGeWl1IiwiaWF0IjoxNDgzNTExMjU1LCJleHAiOjE0ODM1OTc2NTV9.nkeM2LHqibXDqFQ1ZpQ5RseyO3maO5mz8t5ebtnkDUc; c9.live.user.sso=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjcxNjI5OSIsIm5hbWUiOiJwMGxza2ExIiwiaWF0IjoxNDgzNTExMjU1LCJleHAiOjE0ODM1OTc2NTV9.BOxqLKqy6saBOyRjbpccFn8rXTjncW3H_DT2Ysj4vaU; XSRF-TOKEN=cSD1XB8QFAGZFmKWN16R1P%2B1Kwxnyys6cIzOaee02rpkePtyHwuPhmHftQ%2B4YvFvkd3i3BVkvj5z3NLVBk5UEw%3D%3D; _workspace_session=ZEZ6Q2M1aTdFbXA4SzdTc3o2azlnalhmYTR2akVRSGRobFkrUDNwTmlyZ2RPZDdkR0ozamtET2Roa29LMXM4R1h0MUJmZ2lwUHJzWmJKVThOYUxhcjZid1pqZHQzWTRGdmtNZEhjcDZwNWdIN3o5MXcxdnJUUEdCUHhURmlOUE41Uk9ucXY5bkdDUTUzNHo5S3VQSmlnPT0tLXNaakl6S3YzS0VmQmNzZnRBc2NLS3c9PQ%3D%3D--c88551abbcd6419fc848f66f86e9897a5e93ffa8
Host:railie-p0lska1.c9users.io
Origin:https://railie-p0lska1.c9users.io
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://railie-p0lska1.c9users.io/en_AU
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
X-XSRF-TOKEN:cSD1XB8QFAGZFmKWN16R1P+1Kwxnyys6cIzOaee02rpkePtyHwuPhmHftQ+4YvFvkd3i3BVkvj5z3NLVBk5UEw==
```

Server Error:

```
Started POST "/api/feedbacks.json" for 220.244.244.218 at 2017-01-05 03:08:27 +0000
Cannot render console from 220.244.244.218! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by FeedbacksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"data"=>1, "feedback"=>{"data"=>1}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_user' for #<FeedbacksController:0x007f818327e000>
Did you mean?  authenticate):
```

feedbacks_controller.rb

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user

    respond_to :json

    def create
        VisitorRating.create(request_params)
        reply('Thanks for your feedback', :ok)
    rescue
        reply('Unable to save your feedback', :unprocessable_entity)
    end

    private

        def request_params
          params.require(:feedback).permit(:data)
        end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  def self.from_token_payload payload
    # Returns a valid user, `nil` or raise
    # e.g.
    #   self.find payload["sub"]
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "auth_id"
  end

  create_table "visitor_ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "data",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

I changed some variables in Knock's knock.rb config file as per [this](https://auth0.com/forum/t/angularjs-rails-authenticate-401-unauthorized-in-1ms/2244) post in Auth0's forum.

```
Knock.setup do |config|

  config.current_user_from_token = -> (claims) { User.find_or_create_by(auth_id: claims['sub']) }

  config.token_audience = -> { Rails.application.secrets.auth0_client_id }

  config.token_secret_signature_key = -> {
      secret = Rails.application.secrets.auth0_client_secret
      secret += '=' * (4 - secret.length.modulo(4))
      Base64.decode64(secret.tr('-_', '+/'))
    }

end
```

Part of application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  before_action :authenticate, only: :testie

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  respond_to :json

  # Knock is used for user JWT requests
  include Knock::Authenticable

  def angular
    render 'layouts/application'
  end

  private

    def reply(message, status)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json  { render :json =>  {:message => message}, status: status}
      end
    end

end
```

After writing this, I think the problem may have to do with the VisitorRating model not currently belonging to the User model, but I'm new to Rails and not sure about the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your app was created after December 6. If so, your config/initializers/knock.rb should look like

```
Knock.setup do |config|
  config.token_audience = -> { Rails.application.secrets.auth0_client_id }
  config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.secrets.auth0_client_secret }
end
```

Note that the token secret is not base64 encoded: https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/149 and https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/146

It also looks like your app/models/user.rb should be something like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.from_token_payload(payload)
    self.find_or_create_by(auth_id: payload['sub'])
  end
end
```

Your user shouldn't have a password, but the `from_token_payload` needs to actually get the user from that payload.

Other than that, just make sure you remove duplication of stuff in the controllers (probably don't `before_action :authenticate` in the app/controllers/application_controller.rb).